# add one more column based on one table

Tags: mysql

I have an interview question related to how to add one more column based on one table.

The table called `num_users` had two columns `date` , `count_users`

The interviewer wants to me to add one column called 7days_later_count_user

my code is

```
select date, count_users,(select count_users from users where date = date -7) from users
```

But I can not get the answer.

The table is:

```
create table num_users
(
    createdate timestamp default now(),
    count_user int
);

insert into num_users
(count_user,createdate)
values
(100, '2017-02-16 18:22:10.846'), 
(200, '2017-04-02 17:11:21.417'), 
(300, '2017-02-21 11:12:32.574'), 
(400, '2016-08-13 01:28:43.085'), 
(600, '2016-12-07 01:04:39.298'), 
(500, '2017-04-30 13:26:14.496'), 
(99, '2016-12-12 06:50:07.996'), 
(908, '2016-08-20 02:19:45.512'), 
(43, '2016-06-24 19:36:30.978'), 
(87, '2016-08-07 16:25:48.561'), 
(777, '2017-05-04 16:32:15.577'),
(181, '2017-01-19 01:34:14.296');
```

Comment: Are you just trying to retrieve the data or actually insert the new column?

Comment: Hi Josh,Basically I want to show three column, date, count_user, 7days later Count_user

Comment: I think there is a lot of variables you will want to clarify - such as is there already data or primary keys etc. these variables can change the way you go about your answer. But you can add a column to a table by using 'ALTER TABLE num_users ADD 7days_later_count_user datatype'

Comment: basically, the table is really simple:   no primary key,  just create table( date timestamp, count_user int);

Comment: Your question is very unclear. From the comments, I'm guessing instead of altering a table, you want a query that will show the three columns. Edit your question and show an example of the desired output. What is the source for the 7days_later_count_user? Is it the count_user column with a date 7 days after the current row?

Comment: Also, I'm guessing that if you don't understand the question from an interview, let alone the answer, you might be applying for a position that is above your expertise.

Answer (score 0):

You can add columns to tables using **ALTER**
You will want to consider

- whether your column should be nullable
- if you are able to add columns or need to drop the table first
- what datatype you want to use
- how big will the dataset be? for example you can choose between *tiny int*, *bigint*, *int* etc.

this should work for an easy example:

```
ALTER TABLE num_users
ADD COLUMN 7days_later_count_user int
```

Comment: but the interviewer he showed me is not alter table, he mentioned I should use join in, but I dont know how to use it

Comment: hmm not sure i understand from your question. You can find the counts from this though: select count_users, date from num_users
WHERE
date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)

Answer (score 0):

There according to your query you can check with a subquery on the same table which gets the data for the particular date after seven days.

> Note: To get Next 7-day letter date you can use interval

```
select date, count_users, 
(select count_users from users usr where users.date = date_add(usr.date, INTERVAL 7 DAY)) `7days_later_count_user`
from users
```

Or you can use an inner join for the same...

```
select t1.date,t1.count_users,t2.count_users `7days_later_count_user` from users t1
inner join users t2 on t1.date = date_add(t2.date, INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

> Note: For Partial match, you can use **`Left Outer Join`** for the
>   same query.

**EDIT:**
This because you have only one match with given data check the below query may this help you to get the exext data according to your need.

```
select num_users.createdate,num_users.count_user,num_users1.count_user `7days_later_count_user`  from num_users
left outer join num_users num_users1 on cast(num_users1.createdate as date) = cast(date_add(num_users.createdate, INTERVAL 7 DAY) as date);
```

Comment: Yes, Yes,  the inner join is what I want.  Thanks AD.  but my question since I only have one table num_users, how I can define t1 and t2?

Comment: Hi A.D.  But my following question is since I only have one table, how can i define table 1 and table 2?

Comment: Hi AD, I was trying to apply the code but I can not get the result.  select num_users.createdate,num_users.count_user,(select count_user from num_users) as "new"
inner join (select count_user from num_users) on num_users.createdate =(select count_user from num_users).createdate-7;

Comment: Hi AD,   I run the query select createdate, count_user, 
(select count_user from num_users  where num_users.createdate =  date_add(num_users.createdate, INTERVAL 7 DAY)) as`7days_later_count_user`
from num_users; but I stll get null at the 7days_later column

Comment: still not work .  The system shows there is no table called num_users1.  Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: still null my friend.  

the third column is supposed to show  7 days later  count_users data

Comment: check the Edit Part Query.